# Object Slicing in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-slicing

```
    class Base
    {  
         int iBase;

      public:           
         virtual void display()
         {
            cout<<"I am a Base Class"<<endl;
         }        
    };

    class Derived : public Base
    { 
        int iDerived;

     public:
        Derived()
        {
            cout<<"In Derived Default Constructor"<<endl;
            iDerived=10;
        }   

        void display()
        {
            cout<<"I am in Derived Class"<<endl;
            cout<<"value of iDerived  :"<<iDerived<<endl;
            iDerived=100;
            cout<<"value of iDerived  :"<<iDerived<<endl;
        }                
   };
```

**In MAIN:**

```
     Base *varBase;
     Derived varDerived;

     varBase = &varDerived;
     varBase->display();
     varBase->iDerived=10; // Error: iDerived is not a member of Base: ?????
```

Hi all,

I am trying to understand the Object Slicing and trying with some 
sample programs.

I read somewhere with the pointer reference Objcet Slicing will not 
happen.

But with below example I am noticing that `iDerived` is not accessible from `Base pointer(varBase)`, But from the `virtual display method of class` I can access even though it's not in the local scope of display method.

**Now my question is:**

1. Why I am able to access the iDerived variable only with virtual function, is this proper ?
2. How to avoid object slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ has virtual functions, but no virtual data.

You could add the following to simulate it:

```
class Base {
  // What you had before
  virtual int getAnInt() const = 0; // =0 means that Derived must implement this
};
class Derived {
  // What you had before
  virtual int getAnInt() const { return iDerived; }
};
```

Object slicing is entirely unrelated, and doesn't happen in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code doesn't involve slicing at all.  All you have done is invoke basic polymorphism.  By declaring `Base::display()` as `virtual` and by calling `display()` on a `Base *`, you have asked it to dynamically call the member function in the *actual* type of the object being pointed to, which is `Derived`.  The member variables of `Derived` are within the scope of `Derived::display()`, so that is why it compiles and works.

However, you can only directly access member variables (or functions) declared in *Base* via a pointer-to-`Base`.  That is why `varBase->iDerived` does not compile.

Slicing normally involves something equivalent to:

```
Derived d;
Base b = (Base)d;
```

By explicitly assigning/initializing a `Base` object, all the `Derived`-specific members will have been lost (i.e. they have been "sliced" away).

This stuff is relatively fundamental; I would suggest picking up a decent book on C++.  There is a list of good ones here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks for replying. My question as I am not able to use iDerived brom Base *(As it is not in the scope of Base *, As per the Error). How can I able to access from display().

Comment: @user: Oh, sorry, I missed that part of your question.  I will update my answer, hang on!

Comment: Its my mistake, I have to make my question more read able. I have formatted to increase readability.