# Pattern with pure virtual functions getting advantage of polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose the following code:

```
struct Piece_t {
    virtual ~Piece_t() = default;
    std::string type;
};

struct Empty_t : Piece_t {
    Empty_t() { };
    bool run() { return false; };
};

struct Pawn_t : Piece_t {
    Pawn_t() {
        type = "Pawn";
    }
    bool move() {
        return false;
    }
};

struct Board_t {
    using Cols = std::vector<Piece_t>;
    using Board = std::vector<Cols>;
    Board_t(size_t N = 8) : b{ Board(N, Cols(N, Empty_t())) } {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            b[1][i] = Pawn_t();
            b[N - 2][i] = Pawn_t();
        }
        //more init's here...
    }
    Board b;
};
```

Here I have a `Piece_t`, and Im creating a `Board_t`, which has a `std::vector<std::vector<Piece_t>>`.
Fair enough, however, now suppose that I want to add a pure virtual function to `Piece_t`, like `move`:

```
struct Piece_t {
    virtual bool move() = 0;
    virtual ~Piece_t() = default;
    std::string type;
};
```

Doing this, however, is going to give me compilation errors, because I can not instantiate a `std::vector<Piece_t>` like I do in `Board`. This seems strange to me, because I'm actually doing an init with `Empty_t`, and not with `Piece_t`.
So here are my questions:

1. Why is not letting me to compile the code with this modification? Suppose that I' have already implemented `move` in the other two structs.
2. What should be the correct pattern to create the desired behaviour? (Being creating a base class with a virtual pure funct. and later using that definition to getting advantage of polymorphism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object Slicing in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780067/object-slicing-in-c)

Comment: The solution is to use `std:vector<std::unique_ptr<Piece_t>>` or the moral equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why is not letting me to compile the code with this modification?*

You are experiencing [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). `std::vector<Piece_t>` stores *only* objects of type `Piece_t`. Imagine a contiguous array of `Piece_t` classes back-to-back. There is no room to store anything more in between.

Since `Pawn_t` *is a* `Piece_t`, it's sliced back down to `Piece_t` and that part gets stored. Unfortunately an instance of `Piece_t` can't exist since it's an abstract class, hence the compile error.

> *What should be the correct pattern to create the desired behaviour?*

Store *pointers* (or references) to objects instead.

For example, using `std:vector<std::unique_ptr<Piece_t>>`.

```
struct Board_t {
    using Row = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Piece_t>>;
    using Board = std::vector<Row>;
    Board_t(size_t N = 8) : b(N) {
        for (auto& row : b)
            row.resize(N);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            b[1][i] = std::make_unique<Pawn_t>();
            b[N - 2][i] = std::make_unique<Pawn_t>();
        }
        //more init's here...
    }
    Board b;
};
```

Comment: Thanks mate, also I see that `C.67` provides a way to ensure that `slicing` is not going to happen :D

Answer (score -1):

c++ runtime polymorphism is usually obtained instantiating the derived classes on the heap and accessing them via base class pointers/references, for example:

```
class Piece_t {};
class Empty_t : Piece_t {};
class Pawn_t : Piece_t {};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Piece_t>> vec;

std::unique_ptr<Piece_t> e1 = std::make_unique<Empty_t>();
vec.push_back(std::move(e1));
vec.push_back(std::make_unique<Pawn_t>());

vec[0]->some_virtual_method();
```

Note that this is not the only polymorphic mechanism available in c++.
You may want to read a good c++ book while experimenting.